# line-height property: normal + 4px

Tags: html, css

I want the `normal` line-height, plus 4px. I have tried

`line-height: normal + 4px;`

but that doesn't work.

(*Note*: I don't want approximations using percentages.)

Comment: Is it for one or several lines?

Comment: This isn't a typical requirement. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: @thirtydot: I use Chrome with Mac. With those settings, two input boxes that are one under the other "collide" when one has focus. (The focus's glare infringes upon the other input.) Please see http://jsfiddle.net/crYwJ/ for what I mean. I have determined that I always need a _minimum_ of 4px separation to prevent the clash.

Comment: I see. Well, you asked the wrong question. You should have asked how you can solve *that problem* in any way possible, not how to do something odd with `line-height`. But, no problem: you have an answer you're happy with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just take aways Chromes little focus glare?

use the css property `outline: none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/XF6fS/

Comment: No Problem! it just seems to me that if the focus glare is all that is causing the display issue; removing said glare is MUCH easier than playing around with the pixel offsets.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do any arithmetic in CSS. Libraries like [LESSCSS](http://lesscss.org/) allow you to do certain things, but you can't get properties of rendered elements.

You could use percentages to get an approximation, however you should probably set an explicit `line-height` for the elements; this will be the same accross browsers.

Running [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm6Z7/1/) shows the following results:

- FireFox 6: `20px`
- IE 8: `normal`
- Chrome 13: `normal`

Set an explicit height; it's going to be much better compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do it. As said, you cannot do any calculations in `CSS` files. That's why we keep saying that `CSS` is not complete, we have to make `float`s to display our pages properly, which is nonsense when you think about it.

As you have created the css, you can add 4pt yourself. If you don't want to hard-code, you can use CSS frameworks or other languages that create CSS output. Frameworks are fine, but I do not recommend using other languages that create CSS output for you. This is fun, but you will not learn the language and since `CSS` is a hard-to-understand language, you will stuck if you have any errors, misplacements on your page.

So, about your question, you can use `javascript` to `getComputedStyle` and add `4pt` and set the style of the element.

This is the javascript that gets the style:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

### Usage:

```
var height = parseInt(getStyle("elementId", "line-height"));
var earlycss = document.getElementById("elementId").style.cssText
document.getElementById("elementId").style.cssText = earlycss + "\nline-height: " + (height + 4) + "px;";
```

Answer (score 1):

try -

```
line-height: -moz-calc(normal + 4px);
```

But ya this wouldn't be an ideal solution due to cross browser issues and well older browsers won't ideally support this. :). And for further reference - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#functional-notation

Answer (score 0):

im quite sure you can't do math like that with css
try using some javascript to get the line-height and then add 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try using line height in percentage. Eg: Line-height:110% if you want to do it purely in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You could try using em's to define your line height, and then assuming you know the size of your font you can ensure that it's +'x'%

The problem is of course that 90% of the time you can't know the size of your font (or rather that someone won't fiddle with it).