# CSS calc() - Add 4px to "normal" line-height

Tags: html, css, calc

I would like to add 4px to the current "normal" line-height of an element using CSS calc(). Unfortunately, "normal" is not a value that calc() recognizes, but it's the default value for line-height (such as line-height:normal). Thus, the following does not work:

```
*.mystyle{
line-height: calc(normal + 4px);
}
```

How can I add 4px to the "normal" line-height of an element?

Lastly, Although the titles are almost identical, this is not a duplicate of [line-height property: normal + 4px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294315/line-height-property-normal-4px) since the accepted answer there has nothing to do with what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: `line-height: calc(100% + 4px);` should work.

Comment: @robertotomás the "100%" in "calc(100% + 4px)" means take the current font-size (not line-height) and add 4px, since "100%" when applied to the line-height means "A line height in percent of the current font size". So, the line-height may be different than the font-size and thus that solution will not work

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to _add_ to an existing value with CSS (afaik at least). Ideally you'd like something along the lines of `line-height: calc(+=4px)`. If you explain your problem in further detail I'm certain there's another solution to it however.

Comment: sorry, yea that is the font size. in general, the ratio is 1.2, so you could still do this sort of calculation unless you need subpixel precision. But the jquery solution below looks just fine to me :)

Answer (score 3):

## The Issue:

**You can't do this using CSS alone.** Take a look at this excerpt [from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

> #### Formal syntax
>
> **`calc( <calc-sum> )`**
>
> `where 
>   <calc-sum> = <calc-product> [ [ '+' | '-' ] <calc-product> ]`*
>
> `where 
>   <calc-product> = <calc-value> [ '*' <calc-value> | '/' <number> ]`*
>
> `where 
>   <calc-value> = <number> | <dimension> | <percentage> | ( <calc-sum> )`

The value must be a **number**, **dimension**, or **percentage**.

---

## The Solution:

<sub><sup>*(While I realize JavaScript wasn't specifically requested, I'd rather not leave this answer devoid of a true solution.)*</sup></sub>

An alternative would be to use jQuery.

The tricky part is calculating what the CSS `normal` line-height represents.

We can do this by recording the height of our content, adding a line to it, and recording the *new* height - the difference between these two numbers is the actual line-height in `px`.

```js
$(".mystyle").each(function() {
    $t = $(this);
    var $clone = $t.clone();
    $t.parent().append($clone);             //Clone the element

    var initialHeight = $clone.height();    //Get its height
    $clone.append("<br><br>");              //Add a line
    var newHeight = $clone.height();        //Get new height
    var lh = newHeight - initialHeight;     //Difference them to calc line-height in px

    $clone.remove();                        //Clean up

    $t.css("line-height", lh+4+"px");       //Set the new line-height
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mystyle">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu nunc nec tortor lobortis euismod at in nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed ac turpis laoreet, placerat est nec, vehicula
  magna. Vivamus volutpat enim eget neque convallis, elementum accumsan tortor viverra. Morbi faucibus, lorem in laoreet malesuada, felis orci consectetur magna, eget convallis urna nisl at diam. Duis sapien dui, interdum nec ipsum a, porttitor tincidunt
  dolor. Donec ullamcorper eros ac elit pharetra malesuada. Duis placerat ullamcorper libero nec volutpat. Phasellus fermentum eget erat non posuere. Donec orci est, rhoncus a semper et, volutpat sed nisl. Morbi dictum lorem sed justo eleifend congue.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested this out, here is your answer:

```
*.mystyle {
  line-height: calc(100% + 4px);
}
```

Comment: the "100%" in your answer means take the current font-size (not line-height) and add 4px, since "100%" when applied to the line-height means "A line height in percent of the current font size". So, the line-height may be different than the font-size and thus that solution will not work. A "normal" line-height is not always "100%"

Answer (score -3):

Normal implies 100% line-height so you could try
`line-height: calc(100% + 4px);`

Comment: A line height of 100% is not same as normal